# Docx4j Put image and text in the same run

Tags: java, styles, element, inline, docx4j

Is there any way to put three words(one below another) and an image exactly next to them in the same run inside a P element?

I am trying this but it is not working. It displays the String without new lines.

```
private static P addImageToParagraph (Inline inline){
      ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
      P p = factory.createP();
      R r = factory.createR();
      Text t1 = factory.createText();
      t1.setValue("First \n Second \n Third");
      r.getContent().add(t1);
      Drawing drawing = factory.createDrawing();
      drawing.getAnchorOrInline().add(inline);
      r.getContent().add(drawing);
      p.getContent().add(r);
      return p;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Word happily opens the following:

```
<w:p >
  <w:r>
    <w:t>cat</w:t>
    <w:drawing>
      <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" wp14:anchorId="5BCF56C2" wp14:editId="3C402C6A">
        <wp:extent cx="1762125" cy="1085850"/>
        <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="9525" b="0"/>
        <wp:docPr id="1" name="Picture 1" descr="Graphical user interface, application, Word&#xA;&#xA;Description automatically generated"/>
        <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
          <a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" noChangeAspect="1"/>
        </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
        <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
          <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
            <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
              <pic:nvPicPr>
                <pic:cNvPr id="1" name="Picture 1" descr="Graphical user interface, application, Word&#xA;&#xA;Description automatically generated"/>
                <pic:cNvPicPr/>
              </pic:nvPicPr>
              <pic:blipFill>
                <a:blip r:embed="rId4"/>
                <a:stretch>
                  <a:fillRect/>
                </a:stretch>
              </pic:blipFill>
              <pic:spPr>
                <a:xfrm>
                  <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                  <a:ext cx="1762125" cy="1085850"/>
                </a:xfrm>
                <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                  <a:avLst/>
                </a:prstGeom>
              </pic:spPr>
            </pic:pic>
          </a:graphicData>
        </a:graphic>
      </wp:inline>
    </w:drawing>
    <w:t>mat</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

If you want soft carriage returns in your string, try

```
<w:r>
    <w:t>First</w:t>
    <w:br/>
    <w:t>Second</w:t>
    <w:br/>
    <w:t>Third</w:t>
</w:r>
```

Note, you are allowed multiple runs in a paragraph.

Playing around in Word, the following produces the effect you are describing:

```
<w:p w14:paraId="51F5329E" w14:textId="6F4BEDC9" w:rsidR="00593364" w:rsidRDefault="00213A25">
  <w:r>
    <w:t>First</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r w:rsidR="00593364">
    <w:br/>
  </w:r>
  <w:r w:rsidR="00593364">
    <w:br/>
  </w:r>
  <w:r w:rsidR="00593364">
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:drawing>
      <wp:anchor distT="0" distB="0" distL="114300" distR="114300" simplePos="0" relativeHeight="251658240" behindDoc="0" locked="0" layoutInCell="1" allowOverlap="0" wp14:anchorId="7D920551" wp14:editId="0F89E79F">
        <wp:simplePos x="0" y="0"/>
        <wp:positionH relativeFrom="character">
          <wp:posOffset>1069947</wp:posOffset>
        </wp:positionH>
        <wp:positionV relativeFrom="line">
          <wp:posOffset>-548640</wp:posOffset>
        </wp:positionV>
        <wp:extent cx="1764792" cy="1088136"/>
        <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="6985" b="0"/>
        <wp:wrapSquare wrapText="bothSides"/>
        <wp:docPr id="2" name="Picture 2" descr="Graphical user interface, application, Word&#xA;&#xA;Description automatically generated"/>
        <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
          <a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" noChangeAspect="1"/>
        </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
        <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
          <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
            <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
              <pic:nvPicPr>
                <pic:cNvPr id="1" name="Picture 1" descr="Graphical user interface, application, Word&#xA;&#xA;Description automatically generated"/>
                <pic:cNvPicPr/>
              </pic:nvPicPr>
              <pic:blipFill>
                <a:blip r:embed="rId6">
                  <a:extLst>
                    <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
                      <a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0"/>
                    </a:ext>
                  </a:extLst>
                </a:blip>
                <a:stretch>
                  <a:fillRect/>
                </a:stretch>
              </pic:blipFill>
              <pic:spPr>
                <a:xfrm>
                  <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                  <a:ext cx="1764792" cy="1088136"/>
                </a:xfrm>
                <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                  <a:avLst/>
                </a:prstGeom>
              </pic:spPr>
            </pic:pic>
          </a:graphicData>
        </a:graphic>
        <wp14:sizeRelH relativeFrom="margin">
          <wp14:pctWidth>0</wp14:pctWidth>
        </wp14:sizeRelH>
        <wp14:sizeRelV relativeFrom="margin">
          <wp14:pctHeight>0</wp14:pctHeight>
        </wp14:sizeRelV>
      </wp:anchor>
    </w:drawing>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>Second</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r w:rsidR="00593364">
    <w:br/>
  </w:r>
  <w:r w:rsidR="00593364">
    <w:br/>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>Third</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

but me, I'd use a table, 1 row, 2 cols, no borders; text in the left hand cell, image in the right.